# How secure this simple session management?

Tags: security, session

I'd like to create a simple session management script and know what you think about it? Is it logically correct?

I read if https is not available then session_regenerate_id on evey load can be a solution, right?

```
if($_SESSION["user"]["logged"] && is_numeric($_SESSION["user"]["id"])){    
    $id = $_SESSION["user"]["id"];  
    $sid = file_get_contents($id);  // read from db the previous key 
    if($sid == $_SESSION["user"]["key"]){  
        echo "<p><a href='?logout'>logout</a></p>";  
        echo "<p><a href='/login.php'>refresh</a></p>";  
        session_destroy();  
        session_start();  
        session_regenerate_id(true);  
        $_SESSION["user"]["logged"] = true;  
        $_SESSION["user"]["id"] = $id;  
        $_SESSION["user"]["key"] = uniqid();  
        file_put_contents($id, $_SESSION["user"]["key"]);  // write to db the new key 

    }  
    else {
        // logout
    }  
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read if https is not available then session_regenerate_id on evey load can be a solution, right?

A solution for what ? SSL/TLS provides transport level security, protects your data in transit to and from user. Regenerating session Id on every request has nothing to do with trasport security. It's true that nobody will be able to catch your cookie in transit, but that is not the only way somoene can get his hands on this cookie. Ie if your page is prone to XSS someone with a little help of social engineeering can steal your cookie.

Regenerating can increase endpoint (user) security (although it's dissputable) because if someone wil steal the user session ID cookie but Is not fast enough to make a request with it, before user will be prevented from using stolen value (this is unlikely that he won't be that quick).

So in general, your scheme is good if you wan't to leave it that way, it is not substitution for SSL/TLs. And renegeration after login should be a must, regeneration on each request is an addition.

Comment: Actually I'd like to know how create secure login and user handler script in 2012/2013 and what I must do to keep data in safe. Can you recommend me an up-to-date script or description about this problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113225/php-session-regenerate-id-and-authentication-of-users And I also read (but I can find the link) if my script run on a shared host but I can change the session storage dir (tmp) I don't need use custem session management. Is it true? To much information on the net and unfortunately I can't decide which is correct... :(

Comment: Session management is one thing (data binded to user-system conversation) but session is also used for storing-authentication related data, and this is the key of whole problem. You need to design secure session instantiation. One thing is the prefixed storage for your serialized session data, and the other thing is issuing valid session identification token! I would recomend reading: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management it's for java but it's also pretty clear so you would understand it.